# MassTransit with RabbitMQ: MT timing out on second Request/Response

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Working with a Request/Response scenario with MassTransit and RabbitMQ. 
When doing a simple Request/Reply it works multiple times. 
If I publish a message in the request handler it  works on the first request, but the request handler never gets called on the second request and ends up timing out and the message stays in the Server Queue.

It seems like I am missing something; configuration maybe?

The project is at https://bitbucket.org/joeyoung/enterprise-rabbitmq

The client configuration:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddRegistry<WebRegistry>();
    cfg.For<IServiceBus>().Singleton().Use(o => ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
    {
        // configure the bus
        sbc.UseRabbitMqRouting();
        sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/entrprise_client");

        // finds all the consumers in the container and register them with the bus
        sbc.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(ObjectFactory.Container));
    }));
});
```

The Server Configuration:

```
var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.Assembly("Server.MessageHandlers");
        scan.AddAllTypesOf<IConsumer>();
    });
});

var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    // configure the bus
    sbc.UseRabbitMqRouting();
    sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/enterprise_server");

    // finds all the consumers in the container and register them with the bus
    sbc.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(container));
});

// finally inject the bus into the container
container.Inject(bus);
```

Sending the Request:

```
bus.PublishRequest(new CreateProductCommand(correlationId, model.Name, model.Description, model.Price), x =>
{
    x.HandleTimeout(10.Seconds(), () => { timedOut = true; });
    x.Handle<CreateProductCommand.Response>(response => { productId = response.Id; });
});
```

Consuming the Request:

```
public void Consume(IConsumeContext<CreateProductCommand> context)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Consuming Create Product");

    // simulate creating a product
    var productId = "products/1234";

    bus.Publish(new ProductCreatedEvent(productId));

    context.Respond(new CreateProductCommand.Response(context.Message.CorrelationId) { Id = productId});
}
```

The Message:

```
public class CreateProductCommand : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public CreateProductCommand(Guid correlationId, string name, string description, decimal price) 
    {
        CorrelationId = correlationId;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
    }

    public class Response : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; private set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public Response(Guid correlationId)
        {
            CorrelationId = correlationId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the resolution just quickly looking at this. I suggest looking at joining our mailing list so someone else can step up and take look. http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss Also include what version of MT you are using.

Comment: Also, turn on logging and verify that no exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps the container is disposing of the bus instance after the first message is consumed. You can get to the Bus as a property on the IConsumeContext, so there is no need to take a dependency on it in the consumer constructor.

Comment: Enabled logging and not seeing any other errors besides the timeout that is thrown on the second publish. Used the Bus on the consumeContext and that seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris for suggesting to use the Bus on the IConsumeContext. That seems to have fixed it.

So instead of injecting an IServiceBus in the handler's constructor you grab the bus from the context.

```
public class CreateProductCommandHandler : Consumes<CreateProductCommand>.Context
{
    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<CreateProductCommand> context)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Consuming Create Product");

        // simulate creating a product
        var productId = "products/1234";

        context.Bus.Publish(new ProductCreatedEvent(productId));

        context.Respond(new CreateProductCommand.Response(context.Message.CorrelationId) { Id = productId});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same issue but it was caused by 2 microservices sharing the same response queue. I just made sure they had unique names and it works great!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30252273)

Answer (score -4):

I know that you want to use MT with RabbitMQ, I gave up and turned my love toward EasyNetQ, give it a try(-: